# how can I extract data from an executable without executing it in linux

Tags: linux, executable, suse

Hi I have an executable in Linux(display_info.x) that displays some information, is there a way to extract that information without executing the command? i am using suse Linux

Comment: Maybe. Very much depends on what the executable does and what is the kind of information you want to extract. Please edit the question and write down specifically, what you want.

Comment: Where does this executable obtain this information from? Is it embedded in the executable?

Comment: If you know the data is embedded directly into the executable then you can try to use a disassembler and/or a hex-editor to look for the data.

Comment: If on the other hand the executable **builds** the data (ex.: mathematically or by joining several separate pieces or by fetching it from an outside source) then your easiest route would mean running it on a Linux -- ex.: on a bootable stick without installing linux.

Comment: **Try** `strings display_info.x`; see also [`man strings`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings).